# Count number of Properties of an Object in a For Loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, object, do-while

I'm new to JavaScript and since I'm trying to learn thru some exercises I'm having some problem understanding how to make this simple thing to work:

```
var person = {
  name: 'John Potato',
  age: 31,
  weight: '145kg',
  birthday: 'Some day mid July'
}
```

Then, after studying some things about Loops..

```
let counter = 0;

while(counter.length < person){
  counter++;
}
console.log('The person has ' + counter + ' properties')

do{
  console.log(counter++)
} while(counter.length < person[prop]);
console.log('The person has ' + counter + ' properties')
```

Thing is, neither of them work the way I'm expecting. All I want to do is to make it count the amount of properties there are inside the object 'person'

Comment: `counter` is a number. A number has no `length` property. `person` is an object. How do you think `while(counter.length < person)` would work (when `counter.length` would exist)?

Comment: [Working with objects - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`counter.length` is undefined.

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get all the keys and get the *length* property form that:

```js
var person = {
  name: 'John Potato',
  age: 31,
  weight: '145kg',
  birthday: 'Some day mid July'
}
let counter = Object.keys(person).length;
console.log('The person has ' + counter + ' properties');
```

You can also use `for...in` like the following way:

```js
var person = {
  name: 'John Potato',
  age: 31,
  weight: '145kg',
  birthday: 'Some day mid July'
}

let counter = 0;
for(var i in person){
  counter++;
}
console.log('The person has ' + counter + ' properties');
```

Comment: _"Why don't use..."_ - Why don't you spent the time searching for a duplicate to a really easy problem which will definitely already have an answer, instead of adding yet another answer...